# Toggle hide not woking

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple code, i want to hide a `div` if user click on other `div.container` or `button` inside this div
here is my code

```js
$('div, button').click(function(){
  $('.div').toggle('hide');
})
```

```css
div{
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
.container{
  background: pink
}
.div{
  background: blue
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <button>Click</button>
</div>
<div class="div"></div>
```

its work fine when i click on `container` div but its not working when i click on button, i know the porblem is that you fire a click two times.
but how to fix that

Comment: why dont you use $('.div').hide()?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can stop that by preventing the click event from bubbling up the DOM and triggering the click event on the parent with [.stopPropagation()](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/):

```js
$('div, button').click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  $('.div').toggle('hide');
})
```

```css
div{
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
.container{
  background: pink
}
.div{
  background: blue
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <button>Click</button>
</div>
<div class="div"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use below Jquery for the issue.

```
    $('.container, button').click(function(){
      $('.div').toggle(500);
      return false;
    })
```

Comment: this is a false answer the problem isn't the method of hiding the element.

Comment: @John did u read the question  ??? here it is " i want to hide a div if user click on other div.container or button inside this div here is my code "

Comment: yes i read the question, just run the OP code snippet and run j08691 answer and you will understand that your answer is false.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
$('div, button').click(function(){
  $('.div').toggle('hide');
  console.log("hello");
  return false;
})
```